# oTree and JavaScript check if class is active (checked)

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, otree

when I'm running this code:

```
    <div id = "1-round" class="btn-group btn-group-toggle btn-lg " data-toggle="buttons" >
{% for checkbox in form.players_choice %}
    <label class="btn btn-primary rounded mr-3 active btn-lg 1-round" style="margin-bottom:8px;">
        <script>
           $('label').click( function() {
          $(this).addClass('btn-primary').removeClass('btn-default').siblings().removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default');
         if ($('#id_players_choice_0').is(':checked')) {
         x = id_players_choice_0.value};
         if ($('#id_players_choice_1').is(':checked')) {
         x = id_players_choice_1.value};
          alert(x);
         });
        </script>
        {{checkbox}}
    </label>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

I get the value (the x variable) only on the second or third time that I push the button.
Is there a way to fix this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `$('label')` selector will select the labels that are already part of the document. Also, it is not good to put that click handler in a loop as it will multiply the same handler on multiple elements. Move that script to the end of the document, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Also, be sure the declare your variable `x` so that it has the correct scope.

```
<div id = "1-round" class="btn-group btn-group-toggle btn-lg " data-toggle="buttons" >
{% for checkbox in form.players_choice %}
    <label class="btn btn-primary rounded mr-3 active btn-lg 1-round" style="margin-bottom:8px;">
        {{checkbox}}
    </label>
{% endfor %}
</div>
<script>
    $('label').click( function() {
        var x;
        $(this).addClass('btn-primary').removeClass('btn-default')
               .siblings().removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default');
        if ($('#id_players_choice_0').is(':checked')) {
            x = id_players_choice_0.value;
        }
        if ($('#id_players_choice_1').is(':checked')) {
            x = id_players_choice_1.value;
        }
        alert(x);
    });
</script>
```

If you cannot guarantee that the labels are all created before the script executes, then use event delegation:

```
    $(document).on('click', 'label', function() { // ...etc
```

Comment: When the labels are already part of the document? I think this is my problem. Is there another selector I should use?

Comment: I don't understand the first question, but you can use another selector which also works when the labels are not (all) there yet: `$(document).on('click', 'label', function() ....`  The labels are part of the document when the `{% for ... %}` loop has completed.